# Could a fourth family of quarks and leptons account for dark matter?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, quarks, beyond-the-standard-model

In the early universe, could a family of quarks and leptons have formed an electrically neutral particle that is dark matter?

Comment: Neutral composite particles still have nonzero magnetic moments so they can interact electromagnetically, while dark matter does not.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. These particles would still interact via the strong force, and the limit on the dark-matter-dark-matter-interaction cross-section from merging galaxy clusters rules that out. Also, as @Triatticus points out in the comments (which are not preserved for eternity unlike answers): "Neutral composite particles still have nonzero magnetic moments, so they can interact electromagnetically, while dark matter does not."

Comment: If the fourth family of  quarks and leptons  in the early universe had a mass similar to a neutrino perhaps they formed a non composite electronically neutral neutrino .

Comment: Without extra assumptions, this is ruled out by the width of the Z-boson decay, which tells us that there's only three (lighter) families for the Z to decay into. Of course you are free to add extra epicycles to keep your theory alive.

Comment: Shortly after the big bang z bosons had zero mass and zero decay width so there were no families of quarks .The quarks must have become neutral neutrinos .